# Belarus visa application

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, belarus

I wish to go from Dresden, Germany, to Moscow, Russia, via Poland and Belarus. Do I need, and how do I get a transit visa for Belarus?

Comment: How would you be traveling, and how long would you be spending in each intermediary country?

Comment: i want to get the visa when i am in germany.

Comment: But, are you going to be driving? Train? Plane? Spending weeks in each country? days? hours? There are ramifications if you are hitchhiking through and spending a month in each, vs flying into and out of each and spending minutes. For all we know you're starting a country count (of countries visited) and are both independently wealthy and retired. There's a difference between "I want to go from ..." and "I will be flying from ..."

Comment: Not exactly answerable.  There is a procedure and it's not exactly a tourist destination...

Comment: I edited your question to render it answerable. Feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: What is your citizenship/passport holding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a visa to transit via Belarus, unless you are a citizen of the countries listed below, all of which have visa-free access to the country. Quoting from [the website of the Ministry for Foreign Affairs of Belarus](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/):

> Armenia, Azerbaijan, Cuba (for a term not exceeding 30 days), Georgia, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Macedonia (provided that there is a private invitation or tourist voucher), Moldova, Mongolia, Montenegro (for a term not exceeding 30 days provided that there is a private invitation or tourist voucher), Qatar (for a term not exceeding 30 days), Russia, Serbia (for a term not exceeding 30 days), Tajikistan, Turkey (for a term not exceeding 30 days), Ukraine, Uzbekistan, Venezuela (for a term not exceeding 90 days), Ecuador (for a term not exceeding 30 days).

The visa application must be sent to any of [the relevant authorities](http://embassies.mfa.gov.by/index_eng.html). A Belarus transit visa is valid for the 48 hours following your entry in the country. Quoting from [the website of the Ministry for Foreign Affairs of Belarus](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/):

> **Transit visa** (type B) is issued for  transit through the territory of the Republic of Belarus for the stated period, but not more than for 1 year, and is valid for 2 days from the date of entry of a foreign citizen into the Republic of Belarus.
>
> Transit visa is issued for single, double and multiple transit through the territory of the Republic of Belarus in case the foreigner has the visa of the country of his or her final destination.
> If a visa to enter a third country is not required, other grounds for issuance of a transit visa are taken into account, including railroad, motor or airline tickets or booking confirmation.

Comment: NB, this is [no longer true](https://tass.com/economy/1169807) since 2020-07-01, as Belarus now recognises Russian visas (and vice versa), which I assume OP has.